# Sign in button google with correct style

Tags: android, border, google-signin

I want to do a google sign in button with "diferent" style, but i don't know how to do exactly.

I want this style but with a google icon in left:

[image]

So (But with border):

[image]

With Facebook button I can, only I needed put a drawable in "android:background" with this style:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="100dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#415dae"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="270dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        />
</shape>
```

But with google, I tried with "Button" normal in xml, and with "SigninButton" adding a background, and i can't do.

Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

The sign in buttons that come with the Facebook and Google APIs are restricted in what you can change to their design. I would suggest designing your own button according to how you like it and then put an onClickListener to it to handle when to login.

Alternatively you can use `android:onClick="method name here"` right in the button xml and declare a method which takes a view as argument (important).

Comment: I tried with a normal button, but i can do a icon in left, with border and text "google", only i need a style with that. Im using a normal button.

Thank u so much.

Comment: I see what you mean. There are several ways to achieve that and the simplest is to use an ImageButton with an image consisting of the logo and text, preferably slightly higher res or vector. Why do you specifically want to use a custom style? Are you going to reuse that style elsewhere in your app?